# PHP SoapClient only sending some header fields

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to access a SOAP API which requires a custom header for authentication. I can create the header fine, as it's just username, password, id, nice and simple, but for some reason when the actual request goes through it only sends username and password, not id.

I create a SoapHeader:

```
$auth = array("UserName" => $user, "Password" => $password, "ClientId" => $clientId);
$header = new SoapHeader("namespace", "ClientHeader", $auth, FALSE);
$this->client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

I var_dump the created header, client, etc, and verify that UserName, Password and ClientId are all in the header.

```
SoapClient::__set_state(array(
  Extra Fields Removed
   '__default_headers' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    SoapHeader::__set_state(array(
       'namespace' => 'namespace',
       'name' => 'ClientHeader',
       'data' => 
      array (
        'UserName' => 'name',
        'Password' => 'password',
        'ClientId' => 'id',
      ),
    )),
  ),
))
```

But when I make a request only UserName and Password get sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="namespace>
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <ns1:ClientHeader>
    <ns1:UserName>name</ns1:UserName>
    <ns1:Password>pass</ns1:Password>
  </ns1:ClientHeader>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  Remainder snipped
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've checked the WSDL and it specifies that ClientHeader has all three fields, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with that: `<s:complexType name="ClientHeader"><s:sequence><s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ClientID" type="s:string"/><s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string"/><s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string"/></s:sequence><s:anyAttribute/></s:complexType>`

Comment: Have you checked if $cliendId is not null?

Comment: Yup. And it's present in the header and SoapClient var_dump as the expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting ClientId when you should be setting ClientID

Comment: Always the simple things one misses.